# how to dispose the rest of audio player instances when I play another one?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-audioplayers

I have implemented chat app
the messages can be text, video, images and recorded audio.
i have a problem concerning recorded audio message,
I used [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) package to implement recording audio and playing it features.
the list of messages are displayed with ListView;
I want when I play an audio, if there is another audioWidgets that are playing or paused they will be restarted again
this is the link of audio player widget : `[code](https://pastebin.com/B7AHdzXB)`

Answer (score 0):

instantiating the audio player in the widget was the problem in my case.
so I create one instance of audio player with Cubit and I used every time when I play a recorded audio